# Set both RUNASADMIN and WINXPSP2 application compatibility flags with Inno Setup

Tags: windows, inno-setup

I have an Inno Setup installer code and have to modify the compatibility and also privilege mode as Admin.

I have written the following code :

Option 1:

```
[Setup]
PrivilegesRequired=admin

[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers"; \
   ValueType: string; ValueName: "{app}\MyProg.exe"; ValueData: "RUNASADMIN"; 
   Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty uninsdeletevalue; MinVersion: 0,5.1

Root: HKCU; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers"; \
   ValueType: string; ValueName: "{app}\MyProg.exe"; ValueData: "WINXPSP2"; \
   Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty uninsdeletevalue; MinVersion: 0,5.1
```

This code is setting either Run as admin or set Compatibility to Windows XPSP2. It is overwriting the previous value. Hence I moved to multi string option which is my second idea of option 2 below

Option 2:

```
[Setup]
PrivilegesRequired=admin

[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers"; \
   ValueType: multisz; ValueName: "{app}\MyProg.exe"; \
   ValueData: "RUNASADMIN"{break}WINXPSP2"; \
   Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty uninsdeletevalue; MinVersion: 0,5.1
```

This code is adding the multi string in the registry but this has no effect on the properties of exe. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compatibility flags setting is a space-separated string:

```
ValueType: string; ValueData: "RUNASADMIN WINXPSP2";
```